# Not able to put multiple boxes in a single line

Tags: javascript, html, css

[Click here to access the website](http://www.teciexsolutions.in/)

This website is developed using Javascript, CSS and HTML.
We got it developed by a web designer. When we asked him to modify the site he refuses so we tried doing it by our-self.

The designing part in the website is done using CSS. We wanted to put one more button(Testing Services) just before the contact us button. We did the code changes and add the button. But the problem is after adding the button we started getting two lines. First line carries 5 buttons and second line carries 2 buttons.
I tried to fix the problem by changing the text size from 14px to 10px in css but after doing that the text become to small to read.
Then we tried to increase the margin but won't get the result.

Below is Screen shot of the menu after modification--
[image: Screen shot of the menu after modification]

Below is Screen shot of the menu before modification--
[image: Screen shot of the menu before modification]

[Till now we have not updated the actual website so you can't see the second line on the actual website.](http://www.teciexsolutions.in/)

Comment: Please add your code in your question instead of linking to your website. If any other users have the same problem and land on this question in the future, your site may no longer have the issue and this question will not be able to help them.

Comment: Also, what exactly is it that you want to do? This is a logic / design issue, more than a coding issue, isn't it? We can help you if you are stuck somewhere with your code, but you need to make it clear what it is exactly that you want to achieve, what you have tried, and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem of having two lines of menu items already exists on your current website when you scale down your browser window to a width lower than about `1250px`. Give it a try!

To be able to put MORE items in one row you have to decrease the amount of horizontal padding each item has!

In the file `style.css`, Line `1099` you should find the CSS selector `#cssmenu a {...}`. In here alter the `padding: 10px 33px;` to something like `padding: 10px 10px;` because the latter value (33px) specifies the amount of horizontal space the items consume. This should solve your problem for now, but be aware that the problem actually depends on the size of the browser window too. The smaller the browser size, the more likely it is some items break into a new line.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put your

size in %. Now they are 104px. Try with %. Maybe 10% on each

element.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this specific case with that specific added menu item is as follow:

Go into style.css to line number 1099 and where it says
 #cssmenu a you look for padding: 10 33px; and change that to padding: 10px 21px;

Let me warn you that this solution only works if you add Testing Services, otherwise the width will just break again.

There is however not really an allround solution because (sorry to say) your website is coded really really badly.